# How to completely fill table cells with buttons containing different font sizes?

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a way to place differently sized buttons in table cells (1 button each in 1 cell) and have each button fill the cell completely, irrespective of its or other button's font-sizes or other styling aspects.
I have found loads of tutorials on how to fill a single table cell with one button, but as soon as I add more buttons in other cells things do not work anymore for me (creating free space around some buttons, e.g. with smaller font sizes).

Problematic demo code:

```
<html>
 <head> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
  <style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
table {<!--from w  w  w.  j ava2s .  com-->
   border-collapse:collapse;
}

tr, td {
   border:2px solid;
}

tr {
   height:auto;
   text-align:center;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}

td {
   padding:0px;
}

input, select {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
}
</style> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <table> 
   <tbody> 
    <tr> 
     <td> <select> <option>Lorem i</option> <option>Lorem i</option> </select> </td> 
     <td> <input type="button" value="abcdefghijklmno" style="font-size:150%"> </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr> 
     <td> <select style="font-size:200%"> <option>Lorem i</option> <option>Lorem i</option></select> </td> 
     <td> <input type="button" value="test"> </td> 
    </tr> 
   </tbody> 
  </table>  
 </body>
</html>
```

rendering as:
[buttons not filling cells completely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8Hrj.png)

Thanks for any hints on how to achieve completely filled table cells ( without any margins around the buttons inside the cells),

Joost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a working example after further trial and error, expanding upon @iame 's reply:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
    table,
    tr,
    td {
      background-color: red;
      border: 1px solid;
      text-align: center;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    tr,
    td,
    th {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    select,
    option,
    input {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: none;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option>Lorem i</option>
            <option>Lorem i</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td> <input type="button" value="abcdefghijklmno" style="font-size:150%"> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select style="font-size:200%">
            <option>Lorem i</option>
            <option>Lorem i</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td> <input type="button" value="test"> </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
  
table,tr,td{
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
    height: fit-content;
}

tr,td,th{
    margin: 0;
}

select,option,input{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style> 
   </head> 
   <body> 
    <table> 
     <tbody> 
      <tr> 
       <td> <select> <option>Lorem i</option> <option>Lorem i</option> </select> </td> 
       <td> <input type="button" value="abcdefghijklmno" style="font-size:150%"> </td> 
      </tr>
      <tr> 
       <td> <select style="font-size:200%"> <option>Lorem i</option> <option>Lorem i</option></select> </td> 
       <td> <input type="button" value="test"> </td> 
      </tr> 
     </tbody> 
    </table>  
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but as far as I can see the buttons are still not filling the entire table cells?

Comment: No, the input are filling in the <td> element. The spacing you are seeing is that of the border try adding border:none; and also use developers option to inspect the code

Comment: Hm, that does not work for me on Firefox 109, the top left and bottom right cells are not filled completely by the buttons.